# Puppeteer - scrape data from table in correct format

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, javascript-objects, puppeteer

I've been working on a puppeteer app to scrape some data.

I've got this code which works fine but could be improved to give me the data I want to improve it to get the data in a structured way that I can work with.

```
const table1 = await page.$$eval('table:nth-child(3) tbody', tbodys => tbodys.map((tbody) => {
  return tbody.innerText;
}));
```

So tbody allows me to scrape all the TR and TD tags no matter the number of those in the table however I've a problem in that my table has a table row and within that table row it has two table cells.  The first TD is the header of the data in the second TD.

So I have the following HTML:

```
<tr class="header1"><th colspan="2">COS-MOD-000-CAB-PAP-123202</th></tr>

body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)

//THIS IS THE BODY WHICH MY ORIGINAL CODE IS PULLING OUT THE TEXT OF. MY CODE LOOKS AT TDS ONLY WITHIN TRs.
<tbody><tr class="header1"><th colspan="2">COS-MOD-000-CAB-PAP-123202</th></tr>
<tr class="light">
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"><strong>Status:</strong></td>//HEADER
    <td valign="top">Wrong&nbsp;</td> //VALUE
</tr>
<tr class="dark">
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"><strong>Created:</strong></td>//HEADER
    <td valign="top">2019-09-09 17:18:53&nbsp;</td>//VALUE
</tr>
<tr class="light">
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"><strong>Modified:</strong></td>//HEADER
    <td valign="top">2019-09-09 17:21:19&nbsp;</td>//VALUE
</tr>
<tr class="dark">
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"><strong>User:</strong></td>//HEADER
    <td valign="top">fbibsan&nbsp;</td>//VALUE
</tr>
<tr class="light">
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"><strong>BMS Account:</strong></td> //HEADER
    <td valign="top">ABC123 SAS. (SAS)&nbsp;</td> //VALUE
</tr>
<tr class="dark">
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"><strong>Mode:</strong></td>//HEADER
    <td valign="top">FAF&nbsp;</td>//VALUE
</tr>
<tr class="light">
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px;"><strong>Type:</strong></td>
    <td valign="top">BOP&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The structure I need is for each row in the table:

```
HEADER:'VALUE'
```

I hope someone could help.  I'd be very grateful as I've spent days searching now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand the task correctly, here is a simplified example how to get structured data from a table:

```js
const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <table><tbody>
        <tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Key 1</td><td>Value 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Key 2</td><td>Value 2</td></tr>
      </tbody></table>
  </html>`;

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const dataObject = {};
      const tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');

      for (const row of tbody.rows) {
        if (!row.querySelector('td')) continue; // Skip headers.

        const [keyCell, valueCell] = row.cells;
        dataObject[keyCell.innerText] = valueCell.innerText;
      }
      return dataObject;
    });

    console.log(data); // { 'Key 1': 'Value 1', 'Key 2': 'Value 2' }

    // await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I get Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined.  Don't you need to define TR as being the rows?

Comment: No, `tbody.rows` already are table's TRs. The error can mean there are TRs with less then 2 TDs. Is this possible?

Comment: The error seems to be in finding my table element in the first place......the table is a table inside a table so its not finding the exact table using the selector......this is the selector   const tbody = document.querySelector('table:nth-child(3) tbody');  no luck with that but I did a test on your code using just the html and it worked a charm.  Any ideas how to get it to work on my specific table in the browser?  Thanks for your time and expertise!

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the page with the table?

Comment: OK - I found the issue - it is as you say - the first TR in the table has no TDs....<tr class="header1"><th colspan="2">text</th></tr>...can that be skipped?

Comment: `if (!row.querySelector('td')) continue;` — this already should skip TRs without TDs...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the type of you tbody is in the map callback. Hoping you can parse that tbody object somehow.

I think you just need additional parsing and probably just need to add some logic to your existing function.

Here's what i would do:

```js
const table1 = await page.$$eval('table:nth-child(3) tbody', tbodys => tbodys.map((tbody) => {
  // add logic here!
  let parsedTable = '';
  let extractedTRs = tbody.match(/<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/g); // find a way to deconstruct this or regex. what is the type of tbody?
  extractedTRs.map( tr => {
  const tr= str.match(/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/g); //this should return an array...someone check me :)
  parsedTable += `tr[0]:'${tr[1]}' \\n`); 
}
  
  return parsedTable;
}));
```

Comment: I tried this solution and got syntax error that tr=str.match has already been declared.  The tbody is there in the html code of my question....thats the full body.  My original code pulls out the tds within the trs but not in the format I want which is first column of row is really the header and the second column is the value.

Comment: I edited the HTML code to make it clearer what is a header and what is a value in the body